# Ubuntu: run app from terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

Is there any command in Ubuntu to run installed app from terminal?

Comment: You really should work on your question. What do you mean my 'installed app' and 'run from terminal' (in fact you should be able to start all applications installed on the system via terminal)?

Comment: There are ways since Ubuntu defaults to use `.desktop` files to manage apps, which essentially run command from terminal. The global `.desktop` files are inside `/usr/share/applications`; take my `Emacs24.desktop` for example, inside that *text* file, there is a line, `Exec=/usr/bin/emacs24 %F`, where you can see the command is `/usr/bin/emacs24`, therefore it's enough to run that in the terminal. There might subtle changes due to the environment setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hm, run terminal, and simply type program name, if it's on PATH, will be started, e.g. "gimp" or "/usr/bin/gimp". You must, of course, know the name of the program binary you want to run, and it's case sensitive. If you're mac user, there's no "open -a", if you're windows user, program binaries usually don't have ".exe" or ".bat" extensions.

Please, be more specific in your questions in future, thx.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm newby in Ubuntu, and I didn't know, that programm name should be in PATH to run from terminal. Thank you very much for explanation !

Comment: if you value someone's answer or consider it helpful, you may vote it up, you know :-) Have nice experience with Linux :)